# Immutable hard links on ext3/4?

Tags: rsync, ext3, filesystems, snapshot, ext4

In my research on file versioning at the fs level, snapshotting, and related ideas, I took a look at hard-links and exactly what they are and how they behave. Using rsync you can get a pretty slick poor man's snapshotting system up and running on file systems that don't natively support it.

But, can you get immutable hard links on ext3/4 or any other file systems for that matter?

My definition for immutable hard link is: A hard link which, when changed on one location, becomes a regular copy and no longer a hard link.

I would like this because it would enable snapshotting use of the source data to link against instead of a copy of the data (in the case of the rsync snapshotting technique).

I have gigabytes of data that can't be duplicated due to space restrictions but I have enough room if I can intelligently snapshot individual changed files with the rest linked to the source not a copy.

Given all that, is there some other technique, feature or technology I'm really looking for?

Answer (score 2):

There has been a proposal to add a new system call, `reflink()`, which would do exactly what you want. So far, it has not been accepted; however, `ocfs2` (since 2.6.32) already has it as a ioctl (<sup>[[1]](http://lwn.net/Articles/351543/)</sup><sup>[[2]](http://lwn.net/Articles/353501/)</sup>).

A couple of articles from May 2009 on the subject:

- [The two sides of reflink()](http://lwn.net/Articles/331808/)
- [This week's reflink() API](http://lwn.net/Articles/333783/)

An older variant of the idea was called [COW Links](http://lwn.net/Articles/77972/).

Comment: Ah, that looks promising!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are looking for [WAFL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_Anywhere_File_Layout)-style snapshot. It does not exactly use "immutable hard link" semantic, but is very close to it.

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.interlinked.org/tutorials/rsync_time_machine.html
http://rsnapshot.org/

both will work with ext3/ext4.

They aren't exactly snapshots, but, will create a new directory with hardlinks to the prior generation.  Deleting the prior generation will leave the new directory with the correct files.